# Embedded Windows Media Player Set Position is slow

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

So, I have an AxWindowsMediaPlayer control on my form, and I'm looking to, while its playing, change the playback position to another point. I found:

```
    mediaplayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = <position in seconds>
```

But If I call that whilst its playing, it does jump to the right position and claims to keep playing, but in reality the video stops playing.

I've tried pausing/stopping before I change the position and playing afterwards, but no luck.

How can I get around this?

**UPDATE**

So, if I wait long enough, playback will resume again, but it will be a few seconds after the point I told it to jump to.

For example, if I tell it to jump to 15 seconds while its playing, it will jump to 15, `Ctlcontrols.currentPosition` will continue to increment, but the video won't actually start playing again until about five seconds later.

So... why isn't there a five second delay when I load the file? It plays instantaneously when I load it in... And how do I get rid of the delay after the jump?

Comment: I wouldn't complain about a delay, it makes sense to be quicker playing from the start than from an arbitrary point. But I also hate when things start "playing" before they're ready. Maybe there's a way to check if it's actually ready and then make it play...

Comment: Go get your video file and investigate its properties/metadata. It is entirely possible that your video file has **very sparse keyframes** (like one in 5-7 seconds). After a jump, WMP (or rather, the CODEC) is not able to produce any video until a keyframe is passed. That's completely normal for some codecs/profiles.